# update-rc.d not changing order

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to change a process to run latter.

my runlevel

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# runlevel
N 3
```

The rc3.d listing

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ls -1 /etc/rc3.d/
K01avahi-daemon
K01dhcpcd
K01ntp
README
S01bootlogs
S01hostapd
S01ifplugd
S01motd
S01rsyslog
S01triggerhappy
S02apache2
S03cron
S03dbus
S03dphys-swapfile
S03rsync
S03ssh
S03udhcpd
S04lightdm
S05plymouth
S05rc.local
S05rmnologin
```

I want to change the hostapd start

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# update-rc.d hostapd defaults 2
```

After I run the command I get no output and process does not change.

I need to move this after the network interfaces are brought up. Because it interferes with wlan0 getting it ip address assigned.

I'm using Raspbian jessie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that setting up links has been automated to resolve dependencies between services, so `update-rc.d` no longer does anything but call `insserv` nowadays to do all the work. So it ignores your options, and `insserv` looks only at the `# Required-Start:` comments in the header of the init.d scripts to decide what numbers to give them.

You can go back to the old style by setting the **legacy mode**, which you can read about in `man update-rc.d`, and then your command should work.

Alternatively, you can simply change the `/etc/init.d/hostapd` file and **add another dependency**, eg `$syslog` to the end of the existing  `# Required-Start:` line. (I don't have this file to show you the result). Then rerun your command.